# How prove this $f(a)\le f(b)$

Tags: analysis, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and that for any $x\in (a,b)$, the limit
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{h}$$ exists and $$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{h}\ge 0.$$

Show that $f(a)\le f(b)$

this problem is from http://wenku.baidu.com/view/a643e6c26137ee06eff91855.html

Comment: Use the Mean value theorem to obtain 
$$
f(a)+f'(c)(b-a)=f(b).
$$
Using the hypothesis, $f'(c)\geq0$.

Comment: Where is that hypothesis given, @Rafa ? And where is it given that $\;f\;$ is differentiable at all?

Comment: The second limit written in the statement implies that 0.5 derivative is non-negative, right?

Comment: So that means *you* can prove the second limit is equivalent to the existence of the first derivative?

Comment: $$
f'(x)/2=\lim \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{2h}
$$
$$
f'(x)/2=\lim \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{2h}
$$
and adding that
$$
f'(x)=\lim \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)+f(x)-f(x-h)}{2h},
$$
right? Do I made a very obvious mistake?

Comment: @Rafa If $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} (a_h + b_h)$ exists, that doesn't imply that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} a_h$ exists.

Comment: Yep, I just realize that.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = |x|$. It is not differentiable at $x=0$ but the above limit exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in the question is a direct corollary of Theorem 2 in the [linked article](http://www1.au.edu.tw/ox_view/edu/tojms/j_paper/Full_text/Vol-27/No-3/27%283%298-5%28279-301%29.pdf). The following self-contained argument is essentially borrowed from the proof of Lemma 1 in the same article.

Given $\epsilon>0$, define
$$f_\epsilon(x):=f(x)+\epsilon x,\quad \forall x\in[a,b].$$
By definition, for every $x\in(a,b)$,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_\epsilon(x+h)-f_\epsilon(x-h)}{h}=2\epsilon+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{h} \ge 2\epsilon.\tag{1}$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, to show $f(a)\le f(b)$, it suffices to prove that $f_\epsilon(a)\le f_\epsilon(b)$. By reduction to absurdity, assume that $f_\epsilon(a)> f_\epsilon(b)$. Fix an arbitrary $y\in (f_\epsilon(b),f_\epsilon(a))$ and define
$$x_y:=\inf\,\{x\in[a,b]: f_\epsilon(x)<y\}.$$
By definition and the continuity of $f_\epsilon$, $x_y\in (a,b)$ and (i) $f_\epsilon(x)\ge y$ when $x\in[a,x_y]$; (ii) for every $x\in(x_y,b]$, there exists $x'\in (x_y,x)$, such that $f_\epsilon(x')<y$. (i) and (ii) implies that

$$\liminf_{h\to 0}\frac{f_\epsilon(x_y+h)-f_\epsilon(x_y-h)}{h}\le 0,$$
which contradicts to $(1)$ and completes the proof.

Comment: Hello,first Thank you your solution,But I have question: why $x\in [a,x_{y}],f_{\epsilon}(x)\ge y$? why not $f_{\epsilon}(x)\ge y$,when $x\in (x_{y},b)$?

Comment: @nanchangjian: You are welcome. By definition, $x_y$ is at least a lower bound of the set $E=\{x\in[a,b]: f_\epsilon(x)<y\}$, which means that if $x<x_y$, $f(x)\notin E$, i.e. $f(x)\ge y$. Then by continuity, $f(x_y)\ge y$(actually, since $x_y$ is the greatest lower bound, $f(x_y)= y$).

Comment: oh,Thank you very much.+1

Comment: @nanchangjian: Once again, you are welcome.