# How prove this inequality $f(a)\le f(b)$

Tags: analysis, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ is continous on $[a,b]$,and for any $x_{0}\in [a,b]$.

> the limit
>   $$\varliminf_{x\to x^{-}_{0}}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}\ge 0$$
>   show that
>   $$f(a)\le f(b)$$

My try: I found this problem is same as
[How prove this $f(a)\le f(b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517786/how-prove-this-fa-le-fb)

But for my problem,this is inflimit,and the limit form is not same,Thank you

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the existence of the limit that f is differentiable, with derivative larger than $0$ in $[a,b]$so that $f$ is non-decreasing from $a$ to $b$? Or are we conidering the posibility that the limit is $\infty$?

Comment: @user99680: It is $\liminf$, not $\lim$.

Comment: Ah, thanks; should have known it is not that simple.

Comment: @GotLost: Thanks! I don't see how the other answer relates to this on two counts (1) $f$ is not symmetrically differentiable and (2) the $x \uparrow x_0$ restriction.

Comment: @GotLost: I think your approach is a nice one, but different. I cannot (easily) see how to adapt your approach to deal with the $x \uparrow x_0$ requirement (the other direction is immediate). My approach mimics the mean value theorem.

Comment: @GotLost: If I understood correctly, we have $x' \in (x_y,x)$ which would result in $h >0$?

Comment: @GotLost: As an aside, my original answer (to the original question, which did not have the $\uparrow$ restriction) was quite different and simpler (in concept, anyway). The answer below was in response to the $\uparrow$ restriction.

Comment: @GotLost: I must be missing something, I see how the result for $h \downarrow 0$ follows, but I do not see how to get $h \uparrow 0$ from your result.

Comment: @GotLost: I see that $f(x_y) = y$, but for $h<0$, we must have $f(x_y+h) \ge y$, so yes, I do not see how to get the $\liminf_{h \uparrow 0} \le 0$ part.

Comment: @GotLost: Oops, missed that (forgot to reverse the inequality because $h <0$). Thanks! Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @GotLost: Easier to have someone else solve it for you :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f(b) < f(a)$. Let $m = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} <0$.

Let $\phi(x) = f(x)+(x-a) \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a}$. Note that $\phi(a)=\phi(b) = 0$. Since $\phi$ is continuous, $\phi$ has a maximum and minimum on $[a,b]$. Let $\overline{\phi} = \max \phi([a,b])$ and  $\underline{\phi} = \min \phi([a,b])$.

If $\overline{\phi} = \underline{\phi}$, then $\phi(x) = 0$ and $\liminf_{x \uparrow b} \frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b} = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = m < 0$.

If $\underline{\phi} < 0$, then let $x_0 \in (a,b)$ be a minimizer. Then $\phi(x) \ge \phi(x_0) $ for all $ x \in [a,b]$. In particular, for $x < x_0$, we have $\phi(x) - \phi(x_0) \ge 0$, and so $\liminf_{x \uparrow x_0} \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(x_0)}{x-x_0} \le 0$. Since
$f(x) -f(x_0)= \phi(x)-\phi(x_0)+(x-x_0) \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, we have 
$\liminf_{x \uparrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} =m < 0$.

If $\overline{\phi} >0$, let $x_0 \in (a,b)$ be a maximizer. Then $\phi(x) \le \phi(x_0) $ for all $ x \in [a,b]$. In particular, $\phi(x) \le \phi(x_0)$, and so 
$f(x) -f(x_0) \le (x-x_0) \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, or in other words, 
$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} =m$ for all $x \in (x_0,b]$. Now repeat the above process on the interval $[x_0,b]$.

One of two things happens above. Either the process terminates, and we have found a point $x_0$ such that 
$\liminf_{x \uparrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} =m< 0$, or the process does not terminate, and we find a sequence of points $b >x_n > x_{n-1}$ such that 
$\frac{f(x)-f(x_n)}{x-x_n} \le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} =m$ for all $x \in (x_n,b]$.
Since $x_n$ is increasing, we have $x_n \uparrow x^* \le b$. Then the above shows that $\frac{f(x^*)-f(x_n)}{x^*-x_n} \le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} =m$. In otherwords, 
$\liminf_{x \uparrow x^*} \frac{f(x)-f(x^*)}{x-x^*} \le \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a} =m< 0$.

Consequently, if $f(b)<f(a)$, then there exists some $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that 
$\liminf_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} < 0$.

Hence it follows that $f(a) \le f(b)$.

Comment: Thank you,But $b_{k}>c$,so when $a_{k}=c$,then $b_{k}>c$,so you only prove $x\to c^{+}$

Comment: and the similarly, you can prove $x\to c^{-}$,so you only prove $x\to c$ is true,But my problem only have $x\to x^{-}_{0}$,Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. I have shown above that if $f(b)<f(a)$ then there is a point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $\liminf_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} < 0$.

Comment: my problem is $x\to x^{-1}_{0}$,mean that $x<x_{0}$

Comment: I think you can prove this if $f(b)<f(a)$,then there is a point $x_{0}\in [a,b]$, such that $\liminf_{x\to x^{-}_{0}}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_{0}}{x-x_{0}}<0$

Comment: Why do you want to restrict to $x \uparrow x_0$?

Comment: I mean you have prove $x\to x^{-}_{0}$ and $x\to x^{+}_{0}$,but my problem only $x\to x^{-}_{0}$,do you know? Thank you

Comment: I really don't understand your fixation on the direction of approach? Why do you care?

Comment: All you need to do it to show that if $f(b) < f(a)$ then at some $x_0 \in [a,b]$ you have $\liminf_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} < 0$.

Comment: this problem have restric $x\to x^{-}_{0}$,and this problem is my teacher give me.He said this solution is not true.and he tell me

Comment: I see, you **changed** the problem after I had answered it.

Comment: I have changed my answer to use a different approach.