# A continuous and at least zero lower derivative function is increasing.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on the interval $(a, b)$ such that its lower derivative is at least zero on $(a, b)$. Prove that the function $g(x)=f(x)+a\cdot x$ is increasing on $(a, b)$ for any constant $a>0$.
I need to do this homework question and have no idea where to start.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. As it stands, this question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: You need to clarify a few things. Is the $a > 0$ constant same as the $a$ in interval $(a, b)$? Also if $a$ is a constant then it is better to write $ax$ instead of $a(x)$ which makes it look like a function.

Comment: Please check similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/517786

Comment: It appears that there is some confusion regarding the meaning of the term "lower derivative". See the comments to my answer (mostby user Paddling Ghost and my replies to them). Can you clarify the correct definition of "lower derivative" in the context of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's us assume that constant $a > 0$ is different from $a$ in $(a, b)$ and thus we use symbol $k$ in place of $a$. Then we need to show that $g(x) = f(x) + kx$ is increasing on $(a, b)$.

Let $c, d$ be points in $(a, b)$ such that $c < d$. We will show that $g(c) \leq g(d)$. We are given that the lower (or left which is the correct term) derivative $f_{-}'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$. Clearly this means that $g_{-}'(x) = f_{-}'(x) + k \geq k > 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$. Now we know that $$g_{-}'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0^{-}}\frac{g(x + h) - g(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{g(x) - g(x - h)}{h}$$ and this limit is guaranteed to be positive by the given conditions. Hence it follows that $g(x) > g(x - h)$ for all sufficiently small $h > 0$.

Now we divide the real numbers $x$ of interval $[c, d]$ into two sets $L$ and $U$ in the following fashion:

We let $x \in U$ if $g(y) \leq g(d)$ for all $y \in [x, d]$ and remaining numbers are in $L$ so that $L = [c, d] - U$. Clearly $U$ is non-empty as $g_{-}'(d) > 0$ implies the existence of an interval $[d - h, d]$ such that $g(y) \leq g(d)$ for all $y \in [d - h, d]$ so that all points of interval $[d - h, d]$ belong to $U$. Now we need to proceed from here and show that $L$ is empty. This will require the use of Dedekind theorem on sets $L$ and $U$. This would establish the fact that $g(c) \leq g(d)$. Continuing this argument a bit further and noting that $g_{-}'(x) > 0$ we can show that in fact $g(c) < g(d)$ so that that we have strict monotonicity.

Comment: Your answer is right (more or less what I was hinting) but I think it is better not to do other people's homework and give ideas about where to start before giving out the final solution

Comment: Sorry Thomas! but I found it difficult to put my long answer in the form of a hint. do you wish I delete some part of it?

Comment: @Thomas: I have edited my answer in the form of a hint.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
And, yes, you basically solved all, but I can't complain =]

Comment: Would the downvote care to comment?

Comment: The lower derivative is not the same as the left derivative.  Lower derivative involves an infimum, left derivative means we're approaching from the left.  As such, this answer isn't correct for this context.

Comment: @PaddlingGhost: Let OP decide the context of the problem. Anyway this is the first time I have heard of a lower derivative which involves infimum. Can you give a precise definition?

Comment: @PaddlingGhost: If you are talking about the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the ratio $\dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$ as $h \to 0^{+}$ (or as $h \to 0^{-}$) then these are called Dini derivatives. The only use I have seen of them is in proof of the Lebesgue's theorem that any montone function is differentiable almost everywhere. The proof given in "Functional analysis" by Riesz-Nagy uses the term "upper and lower right-derived numbers" (they are using only the case when $h \to 0^{+}$). I am not very clear if the OP meant these things.

Comment: @PaddlingGhost: Also I have clearly specified what I have assumed to be the meaning of a lower derivative (and also mentioned that it should have been called a left derivative). But looks like OP did not have any problem with what I have written. Unless further confirmed by OP I don't see any point to change my answer to use Dini derivatives.

Comment: This question seems remarkably similar to a problem in an analysis text by Royden-Fitzpatrick, otherwise I probably wouldn't have said anything.  They define the lower derivative as the $\lim_{h\to0}\left[ \inf_{0<|t|\le h}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} \right]$.  The upper derivative is defined with $\sup$ in place of $\inf$.  I wasn't aware that left and right derivatives might be referred to as lower and upper derivatives respectively.

Comment: @PaddlingGhost: I got your point. I will ask OP via comment to clarify what is meant by "lower derivative". I believe the question is slightly more difficult under the definition of lower derivative you are quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the opposite is true : $g(x)=f(x) + a.x$ is non increasing.
$\exists x, z$ such that $g(x) > g(z)$.

You can take the sup on the x and the inf on the z (prove that it leads to one point y) that verify it (with x <= z) and then use the definition of lower derivative at y to find that it is absurd.